# I do not understand why it's saying an operator is expected for female but not male

Tags: prolog

```
male(X).
female(X).
```

this is my code. If my query is:

```
male(John).
female(Jane).
```

It gives me a syntax error for female but not for male. I don't see where this issue is coming from

Comment: In Prolog, *atoms* start with lower case, and anything starting upper case is a *variable*. `X` is a variable. So `male(X).` says anyone/anything is `male`, and `female(X).` says anyone/anything is `female`. You probably first of all want real facts, such as, `male(john).` and `female(jane).`. `John` and `Jane` are variables, not specific names.

Comment: You query should likely be a **conjunction**: `male(Male), female(Female).`

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the ability to comment yet, but: lurker is right about calling the predicate different and about variables starting with upper case letters.

However, to add to that, if you are trying to make a predicate where *any* variable passed in is found to be male or female, then there is no point in specifying the variable X. You can, and should, simply use the anonymous variable `_`.

```
male(_).
female(_).
```

I'm not sure why exactly you would want to have every call to male/female succeed, but since that's already what your code does, the above will fix the warning you should be getting about X being a singleton variable (a variable that is only used once).

Comment: Just one tiny nitpick: Variables start with an upper case letter *or underscore*. The latter is for example how you teach Prolog in Japan.